# Protection in my php form

Tags: php, jquery

I'm good with HTML, CSS and not too bad with jQuery but php I'm a total loss! Could I get some help with this Form, what is the best way to add protection into this existing php code I use on my site.

This is the page with the tutorial for all the code http://jorenrapini.com/blog/css/jquery-validation-contact-form-with-modal-slide-in-transition

This is my site **REMOVED LINK**

This is the php from the tutorial used for the form that I would appreciate some assistance with adding proper protection.

```
<?php
//declare our variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
//get todays date
$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
//set a title for the message
$subject = "Message from Your Website";
$body = "From $name, \n\n$message";
$headers = 'From: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

//put your email address here
mail("youremail@domain.com", $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
<!--Display a thankyou message in the callback -->
<div id="mail_response">
    <h3>Thank you <?php echo $name ?>!</h3><br />
    <p>I will answer your message soon as possible.</p><br /><br /><br />
    <h5>Message sent on: </h5>
    <p><?php echo $todayis ?></p>
</div>
```

------ Okay to clarify this a bit more ------

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/

This is one of the many articles I've been reading over the past two weeks on Cross-Site Request Forgeries so how do you apply or add basic protection similar to this to a form like I am using

Comment: *Data coming from the client - e.g. from `_POST` - should not be trusted.* In this case a user could, at the very least, inject custom mail headers.

Comment: what do you mean by protection?

Comment: protection with what??? your codes looks fine ...

Comment: You can add multiple addresses to `Reply-To`.

Comment: Like @user2246674 said you can **never trust POST variables**. It's nice for usability that the form validates some field. But that does not add any protection. You'll need to validate on the server side as well.

Comment: How to Avoid Email Injection and Mail Form Script Hijacking from what I have been reading would be the most important I believe.

Comment: if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "E-mail is not valid";
   }
 else
   {
   echo "E-mail is valid";
   }

Answer (score 1):

```
mail("youremail@domain.com", $subject, $body, $headers);
```

can send you the mail, obviously, but you need to create a message to check if the mail function was not successful.

So,

```
if(mail("youremail@domain.com", $subject, $body, $headers)){
  echo 'Your email is sent';
}else{
  echo 'email is not sent';
}
```

The above code, will guarantee, that if there was a problem with `mail()` the user would see a costume-built message than the actual error exposing your code and directory

Comment: So add that to the php and then write something for the ajax to call if it fails so it doesn't go to the root basically is what is needed then.

Comment: I appreciate your input, my fault for not specifying what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. and as far as securing email is concerned, even though w3schools is a sloppy place to learn proper codding, I would suggest you look at **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_secure_mail.asp)** link

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter the postvalues against xss. For txt-mails u should strip out all tags in a professional way. Dont use only strip_tags()! For your header data strip out all whitespaces too.

Comment: Any suggestion on where I can read up on that Mamuz so I can apply it to this code, or is it back to square one again.

Comment: for that its better to use frameworks like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and [PHPIds](https://phpids.org/).

Comment: Ugh, okay thanks for the info, so it's back to the books. Man I hate forms with a passion. PHPIDS looks pretty good though.

Comment: for csrf protection in forms you have to create a hidden hash-value.
with this value you validate the submit from where the submit is.

Comment: Yeah, I got a chance to read more of the PHPIDS and it's more just the detection side, needs to be set up on the server, the server has to be Apache2 and requires at least PHP 5.3.0... so if I ran the server this would surly of interest. So it kinds of goes back to your comment of creating the value and validating that so I guess I'm back to searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [ESAPI project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API), while the PHP version is not suitable for production use (based on what they write), you can still get an understanding of what input validation and security means for your service.

Comment: That's my problem Zuck I've back revisiting forms once again and have been reading for the last two weeks conflicting versions of what is required... from snippets to stop the creation of cc's against highjacking to Cross-Site Request Forgery and was hoping for something to clarify before my head explodes. :lol: